# How to get static URL Links in GWT for different pages

Tags: url, gwt, static, hyperlink, gwt-history

I want to build a multi page website and I need a way to refer to another GWT page (panel) how can I do it such that the links are static?

Comment: This is a duplicate of many SO questions: search for "gwt multiple".

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues in your questions:

1. how to specify the url of a gwt page.
2. how to ensure that url is static.
3. how to create a link to that gwt page from another gwt page.

A GWT url is effected by the module name and package namespace and can be modified by the rename-to attribute. Say, the GWT module description file is named whatever.gwt.xml; and whatever module is placed at package namespace zoom.wonderful.world . The url of the module would be http ://hostnamespace:port/zoom.wonderful.world.whatever. But you can use the rename-to attribute to change it , the url would be http ://hostnamespace:port/holycow.

But ... your module is not accessible by url unless you have an entrypoint - i.e. a gwt java file that implements EntryPoint.

You can have more than one entry point in a module, but under most circumstances my opinion says that you should not unless you wish to begin a career into the most confusgated GWT code contest. The ui representations of all the entry points in a module would overlap. A similar confusgating overlap effect is available if you inherit an entry point.

Behind my mind, I keep asking why you deliberately ask "static url", because the url of the entry point of a module is indeed static.

Then in your other "gwt page", you merely include list the "static urls" of all the "gwt pages" either
- in the hosting html file (which launches the module javascript-compiled files)
- or, within a gwt widget that allows url links or html code to be included.

http://h2g2java.blessedgeek.com/2011/02/uibinder-check-list.html